# Handle browser dialog window without focus

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, autoit

I have a `Selenium WebDriver` based script to automate file uploading. It uploads list of files one by one. I use `AutoIT` script to handle dialog window, file chooser window. Parameter `$CmdLine[1]` contains the path of actual file.

```
ControlFocus("Open a file","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open a file","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open a file","","Button1")
```

I execute it from `Java` code as following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(autoITExecutable);
```

It opens dialog window, so it can't work without focus on browser window.

File upload field works like this demo:
https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/

Comment: And using `element.sendKeys()` to upload the file won’t work because... ?

Comment: @JimEvans : I use that solution in most of the times, but it is not working with this field, it couldn't receive the file.

Comment: @plaidshirt, possible to have a look at the site? Also can you post the html of the element in question here?

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Element looks like this: `<input id="fileup" type="file" name="inputFile" class="fileInput" title="Choose a file!" onchange="document.getElementById('file-path-to-file').value = this.value.split('\\')[this.value.split('\\').length-1];" multiple="">`

Comment: @plaidshirt, what happens when you do `sendKeys` on this field? Nothing happens or when you submit nothing happens? Can you also check the network tab and see what is wrong in the post data that goes? Or are there any console errors. In most cases the situation can be handled using sendkeys and some additional workaround code. So going to use native windows is usually never needed

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Seemly nothing happens. It seems just a button, without any drag and drop functionality. When it is clicked, it opens a dialog window.

Comment: @plaidshirt, without access to a sample page it is hard to say how to solve this. Either create a jsfiddle for use to test or provide a publicly accessible url

Comment: @TarunLalwani : It is similar to this site: https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/ (File 1 of 2 and File 2 of 2 fields.)

Comment: Works for me through selenium

Comment: @TarunLalwani : Could you please share your code/script as an answer?

Comment: @plaidshirt, done shared the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran simple script for the link you gave and it works great

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/")

driver.find_element_by_name("uploadname1").send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/test.csv")

driver.find_element_by_name("email_address").send_keys("none@getnada.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("first_name").send_keys("Tarun")
driver.find_element_by_id("uploadbutton").click()
```

[image: uploaded]

Comment: Thanks, maybe I recorded not the right element. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: It is tough to say without having looking at the page, each page may create a unique situation. Like firing some event which does some other processing, you should execute javascript to fire those event if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try your code in similar format as shown below and try:

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload") // enter the title of the pop up

Send("Path of the file to enter")   // enter the path of the file to upload

Send("{ENTER}") / press enter
```

Comment: It types characters of file path one by one, so it is slower and dialog window is opened too.

Comment: It is about AutoIT, not awt Robot.

Comment: Try using ControlSetText() instead of Send() on the open file dialog? It should be much faster?

Comment: @garbb : Yes. maybe faster. but if dialog is opened it is not the solution I am looking for.